# Como criar um Helper para criação de Datepicker

Tags: c#, mvc, datepicker, helper

Gostaria de criar um Helper MVC para a criação de um **DatePicker**.

Exemplo:

```
@Html.DatePicker();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verifiquei que posso instalar no meu projeto via Nuget esse helper.

```
@Html.DatePickerFor(model => model.Date)
```

https://www.nuget.org/packages/DatePickerHTMLHelper/